# Is any alternatives of ng-repeat in Angular.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a web-app, using Angular.js. I need to process huge data on many places. ng-repeat is taking too much time to process data i have thousand of data in my array, it's so time consuming for process data. So please help me if there is better way available for this situation instead of ng-repeat ? Please help me.

Comment: It would be helpful to show us a sample of what you are doing. There are tricks such as one-time binding that can make `ng-repeat` more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options (can be combined):

1. Pre-process the data and only use `ng-repeat` on the final result - i.e. once you've done all you need and you have a simple data array (e.g. avoid ng-if and other logic within the loop)
2. Use pagination / infinite scroll depending on the context and view needs
3. Make an exception to improve performance and get out of the angular world if none of the above helps:

   - You could use faster DOM manipulation - e.g. use the DOM API directly
   - Or you could generate part of the page on the server-side and combine the SPA (angular) with that generated result

Of course it all depends on the context, the use case you mention is very generic.

Comment: thanks for your response . I used pagination but it's not working as i want . So could you please explain a bit more about , How to i can use DOM API directly ? I am getting API response in my controller and set it in $scope.list = [] ; and iterating on HTML page.

Comment: Add to that avoid `track by $index` and use one-time binding.